# Add Header Information to TCP SYN/ACK Packets

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am working on a project that involves sending TCP packets using the socket library in python. The packets are sent through a virtual serial port. When the socket pushes the packets into the virtual serial port, another thread reads the packet out of the port and then sends it over one of eight unique serial ports. The thread determines which serial port to send it over based on packet type and IP.

For example, SYN/ACK packets are sent over all serial ports. For data packets, the destination IP is cross-referenced with a list of IPs and serial port numbers. So IP 10.10.10.10 might be associated with serial port 0, for instance.

Due to changes in the system, we no longer want to send SYN/ACK packets over all serial ports. However, the routing list is not created until the connection is actually established. This means that there is no way to cross-reference the destination IP in the packet to a particular serial port number.

I understand this situation is quite unique and that it is not a normal use case. It may sound confusing, but there is a purpose for why the system is designed this way.

The system knows the serial port that it wants to send the data on prior to the packet being sent through the socket. Is there a way to attach an integer (0-7) to the TCP packet header for SYN/ACK packets? If it was in the header, we could read that value and send it over the correct serial port.

Comment: Unless you're using raw sockets, I don't think there's any way to manipulate the header directly.

Comment: If the routing list isn't created until after the connection is established, how does the caller know what port number to put in the header?

Comment: The caller does not know, per se. It has a list of possible IPs that could be on the network. When it identifies a node, it attempts to connect to it by checking all possible IPs and seeing which socket is created successfully. The sockets with incorrect IPs time out.

Comment: So instead of sending over all serial ports, you want to loop over the ports until it succeeds?

Comment: A CV system determines which serial port the other node is on. We know which port the packet should be sent on, but we do not know the IP. When the packet is read from the socket, we know the IP we want to try on a particular serial port, but not the serial port it should be sent on. We want to loop through all the possible IPs on the particular serial port until it succeeds. The previous solution was to loop through all IPs over all serial ports until it succeeds.